# Nested ngFor in Angular 2

Tags: json, angular, angular2-template, ngfor

I have question because I can't resolve this problem. I try use *ngFor in my code. Unfortunately I doing something wrong in nested ngFor. So I write ugly code but it's only for show what I need to do:

```
<tabset #staticTabs>


                <tab heading="{{renovation[0].rooms[0].roomName }} {{i}}" >

                  <table class="table">
                        <thead>
                        <!-- SORTOWANIE -->
                            <tr>
                                <th>Lp</th>
                                <th>Rodzaj robót</th>
                                <th>Koszt materiałów</th>
                                <th>Koszt robocizny</th>
                                <th>Akceptacja</th> 
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>{{renovation[0].rooms[0].roomRows[0].id}}</td>
                                <td>{{renovation[0].rooms[0].roomRows[0].typeOfWorks}}</td>
                                <td>{{renovation[0].rooms[0].roomRows[0].costOfMaterials}}</td>
                                <td>{{renovation[0].rooms[0].roomRows[0].costOfWorks}}</td>
                                <td>{{renovation[0].rooms[0].roomRows[0].accept}}</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>{{renovation[0].rooms[0].roomRows[1].id}}</td>
                                <td>{{renovation[0].rooms[0].roomRows[1].typeOfWorks}}</td>
                                <td>{{renovation[0].rooms[0].roomRows[1].costOfMaterials}}</td>
                                <td>{{renovation[0].rooms[0].roomRows[1].costOfWorks}}</td>
                                <td>{{renovation[0].rooms[0].roomRows[1].accept}}</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>{{renovation[0].rooms[0].roomRows[2].id}}</td>
                                <td>{{renovation[0].rooms[0].roomRows[2].typeOfWorks}}</td>
                                <td>{{renovation[0].rooms[0].roomRows[2].costOfMaterials}}</td>
                                <td>{{renovation[0].rooms[0].roomRows[2].costOfWorks}}</td>
                                <td>{{renovation[0].rooms[0].roomRows[2].accept}}</td>
                            </tr>
                             <tr>
                                <td>{{renovation[0].rooms[0].roomRows[3].id}}</td>
                                <td>{{renovation[0].rooms[0].roomRows[3].typeOfWorks}}</td>
                                <td>{{renovation[0].rooms[0].roomRows[3].costOfMaterials}}</td>
                                <td>{{renovation[0].rooms[0].roomRows[3].costOfWorks}}</td>
                                <td>{{renovation[0].rooms[0].roomRows[3].accept}}</td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>

                  </table>

                </tab>

                <tab heading="{{renovation[0].rooms[1].roomName }}" >

                   <table class="table">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Lp</th>
                                <th>Rodzaj robót</th>
                                <th>Koszt materiałów</th>
                                <th>Koszt robocizny</th>
                                <th>Akceptacja</th> 
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>{{renovation[0].rooms[1].roomRows[0].id}}</td>
                                <td>{{renovation[0].rooms[1].roomRows[0].typeOfWorks}}</td>
                                <td>{{renovation[0].rooms[1].roomRows[0].costOfMaterials}}</td>
                                <td>{{renovation[0].rooms[1].roomRows[0].costOfWorks}}</td>
                                <td>{{renovation[0].rooms[1].roomRows[0].accept}}</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>{{renovation[0].rooms[1].roomRows[1].id}}</td>
                                <td>{{renovation[0].rooms[1].roomRows[1].typeOfWorks}}</td>
                                <td>{{renovation[0].rooms[1].roomRows[1].costOfMaterials}}</td>
                                <td>{{renovation[0].rooms[1].roomRows[1].costOfWorks}}</td>
                                <td>{{renovation[0].rooms[1].roomRows[1].accept}}</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>{{renovation[0].rooms[1].roomRows[2].id}}</td>
                                <td>{{renovation[0].rooms[1].roomRows[2].typeOfWorks}}</td>
                                <td>{{renovation[0].rooms[1].roomRows[2].costOfMaterials}}</td>
                                <td>{{renovation[0].rooms[1].roomRows[2].costOfWorks}}</td>
                                <td>{{renovation[0].rooms[1].roomRows[2].accept}}</td>
                            </tr>
                             <tr>
                                <td>{{renovation[0].rooms[1].roomRows[3].id}}</td>
                                <td>{{renovation[0].rooms[1].roomRows[3].typeOfWorks}}</td>
                                <td>{{renovation[0].rooms[1].roomRows[3].costOfMaterials}}</td>
                                <td>{{renovation[0].rooms[1].roomRows[3].costOfWorks}}</td>
                                <td>{{renovation[0].rooms[1].roomRows[3].accept}}</td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>

                  </table>

                </tab>

                 <tab heading="{{renovation[0].rooms[2].roomName }}" >

                   <table class="table">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Lp</th>
                                <th>Rodzaj robót</th>
                                <th>Koszt materiałów</th>
                                <th>Koszt robocizny</th>
                                <th>Akceptacja</th> 
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>{{renovation[0].rooms[2].roomRows[0].id}}</td>
                                <td>{{renovation[0].rooms[2].roomRows[0].typeOfWorks}}</td>
                                <td>{{renovation[0].rooms[2].roomRows[0].costOfMaterials}}</td>
                                <td>{{renovation[0].rooms[2].roomRows[0].costOfWorks}}</td>
                                <td>{{renovation[0].rooms[2].roomRows[0].accept}}</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>{{renovation[0].rooms[2].roomRows[1].id}}</td>
                                <td>{{renovation[0].rooms[2].roomRows[1].typeOfWorks}}</td>
                                <td>{{renovation[0].rooms[2].roomRows[1].costOfMaterials}}</td>
                                <td>{{renovation[0].rooms[2].roomRows[1].costOfWorks}}</td>
                                <td>{{renovation[0].rooms[2].roomRows[1].accept}}</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>{{renovation[0].rooms[2].roomRows[2].id}}</td>
                                <td>{{renovation[0].rooms[2].roomRows[2].typeOfWorks}}</td>
                                <td>{{renovation[0].rooms[2].roomRows[2].costOfMaterials}}</td>
                                <td>{{renovation[0].rooms[2].roomRows[2].costOfWorks}}</td>
                                <td>{{renovation[0].rooms[2].roomRows[2].accept}}</td>
                            </tr>
                             <tr>
                                <td>{{renovation[0].rooms[2].roomRows[3].id}}</td>
                                <td>{{renovation[0].rooms[2].roomRows[3].typeOfWorks}}</td>
                                <td>{{renovation[0].rooms[2].roomRows[3].costOfMaterials}}</td>
                                <td>{{renovation[0].rooms[2].roomRows[3].costOfWorks}}</td>
                                <td>{{renovation[0].rooms[2].roomRows[3].accept}}</td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>

                  </table>

                </tab>


                <tab heading="{{renovation[0].rooms[3].roomName }}" >

                   <table class="table">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Lp</th>
                                <th>Rodzaj robót</th>
                                <th>Koszt materiałów</th>
                                <th>Koszt robocizny</th>
                                <th>Akceptacja</th> 
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>{{renovation[0].rooms[3].roomRows[0].id}}</td>
                                <td>{{renovation[0].rooms[3].roomRows[0].typeOfWorks}}</td>
                                <td>{{renovation[0].rooms[3].roomRows[0].costOfMaterials}}</td>
                                <td>{{renovation[0].rooms[3].roomRows[0].costOfWorks}}</td>
                                <td>{{renovation[0].rooms[3].roomRows[0].accept}}</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>{{renovation[0].rooms[3].roomRows[1].id}}</td>
                                <td>{{renovation[0].rooms[3].roomRows[1].typeOfWorks}}</td>
                                <td>{{renovation[0].rooms[3].roomRows[1].costOfMaterials}}</td>
                                <td>{{renovation[0].rooms[3].roomRows[1].costOfWorks}}</td>
                                <td>{{renovation[0].rooms[3].roomRows[1].accept}}</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>{{renovation[0].rooms[3].roomRows[2].id}}</td>
                                <td>{{renovation[0].rooms[3].roomRows[2].typeOfWorks}}</td>
                                <td>{{renovation[0].rooms[3].roomRows[2].costOfMaterials}}</td>
                                <td>{{renovation[0].rooms[3].roomRows[2].costOfWorks}}</td>
                                <td>{{renovation[0].rooms[3].roomRows[2].accept}}</td>
                            </tr>
                             <tr>
                                <td>{{renovation[0].rooms[3].roomRows[3].id}}</td>
                                <td>{{renovation[0].rooms[3].roomRows[3].typeOfWorks}}</td>
                                <td>{{renovation[0].rooms[3].roomRows[3].costOfMaterials}}</td>
                                <td>{{renovation[0].rooms[3].roomRows[3].costOfWorks}}</td>
                                <td>{{renovation[0].rooms[3].roomRows[3].accept}}</td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>

                  </table>

                </tab>



    </tabset>
```

That is my data.json:

```
 import { InMemoryDbService, InMemoryBackendConfig } from 'angular-in-memory-web-api';

import {IRenovationList} from './renovation-list/renovation-list';

export class RenovationData implements InMemoryDbService, InMemoryBackendConfig {
    createDb() {
        let renovations: IRenovationList[] = [

        {
                'id': 1,
                'name': 'remont',
                'zipCode': 500,
                'rooms': [
                    {
                        "roomId": 1,
                        "roomName": "Kitchen",
                        "roomRows": [
                                {   
                                "id": 1,
                                "typeOfWorks": "Malowanie ścian",
                                "costOfMaterials": 1500,
                                "costOfWorks": 2100,
                                "accept": false
                                },
                                {
                                "id": 2,
                                "typeOfWorks": "Podłogi",
                                "costOfMaterials": 2650,
                                "costOfWorks": 1800,
                                "accept": true
                                },
                                {
                                "id": 3,
                                "typeOfWorks": "Okna",
                                "costOfMaterials": 1200,
                                "costOfWorks": 450,
                                "accept": true
                                },
                                {
                                "id": 4,
                                "typeOfWorks": "Drzwi",
                                "costOfMaterials": 850,
                                "costOfWorks": 250,
                                "accept": true
                                }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "roomId": 2,
                        "roomName": "Toilet",
                        "roomRows": [
                                {   
                                "id": 1,
                                "typeOfWorks": "Malowanie ścian",
                                "costOfMaterials": 1524500,
                                "costOfWorks": 30,
                                "accept": false
                                },
                                {
                                "id": 2,
                                "typeOfWorks": "Podłogi",
                                "costOfMaterials": 5650,
                                "costOfWorks": 14550,
                                "accept": true
                                },
                                {
                                "id": 3,
                                "typeOfWorks": "Okna",
                                "costOfMaterials": 1200,
                                "costOfWorks": 450,
                                "accept": true
                                },
                                {
                                "id": 4,
                                "typeOfWorks": "Drzwi",
                                "costOfMaterials": 850,
                                "costOfWorks": 250,
                                "accept": true
                                }

                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "roomId": 3,
                        "roomName": "Corridor",
                        "roomRows": [
                            {   
                                "id": 1,
                                "typeOfWorks": "Malowanie ścian",
                                "costOfMaterials": 1500,
                                "costOfWorks": 2100,
                                "accept": false
                                },
                                {
                                "id": 2,
                                "typeOfWorks": "Podłogi",
                                "costOfMaterials": 2650,
                                "costOfWorks": 1800,
                                "accept": true
                                },
                                {
                                "id": 3,
                                "typeOfWorks": "Okna",
                                "costOfMaterials": 1200,
                                "costOfWorks": 450,
                                "accept": true
                                },
                                {
                                "id": 4,
                                "typeOfWorks": "Drzwi",
                                "costOfMaterials": 850,
                                "costOfWorks": 250,
                                "accept": true
                                }
                        ]
                    },
                        {
                        "roomId": 4,
                        "roomName": "Bathroom",
                        "roomRows": [
                            {   
                                "id": 1,
                                "typeOfWorks": "Malowanie ścian",
                                "costOfMaterials": 1500,
                                "costOfWorks": 2100,
                                "accept": false
                                },
                                {
                                "id": 2,
                                "typeOfWorks": "Podłogi",
                                "costOfMaterials": 2650,
                                "costOfWorks": 1800,
                                "accept": true
                                },
                                {
                                "id": 3,
                                "typeOfWorks": "Okna",
                                "costOfMaterials": 1200,
                                "costOfWorks": 450,
                                "accept": true
                                },
                                {
                                "id": 4,
                                "typeOfWorks": "Drzwi",
                                "costOfMaterials": 850,
                                "costOfWorks": 250,
                                "accept": true
                                }
                        ]
                    },
                ]

            },
            {
                'id': 2,
                'name': 'remont testowy',
                'zipCode': 500555,
                'rooms': [
                    {
                        "roomId": 1,
                        "roomName": "Kuchnia",
                        "roomRows": [
                                {   
                                "id": 1,
                                "typeOfWorks": "Malowanie ścian",
                                "costOfMaterials": 1500,
                                "costOfWorks": 2100,
                                "accept": false
                                },
                                {
                                "id": 2,
                                "typeOfWorks": "Podłogi",
                                "costOfMaterials": 2650,
                                "costOfWorks": 1800,
                                "accept": true
                                },
                                {
                                "id": 3,
                                "typeOfWorks": "Okna",
                                "costOfMaterials": 1200,
                                "costOfWorks": 450,
                                "accept": true
                                },
                                {
                                "id": 4,
                                "typeOfWorks": "Drzwi",
                                "costOfMaterials": 3850,
                                "costOfWorks": 250,
                                "accept": true
                                }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "roomId": 2,
                        "roomName": "Salon",
                        "roomRows": [
                                {   
                                "id": 1,
                                "typeOfWorks": "Malowanie ścian",
                                "costOfMaterials": 2500,
                                "costOfWorks": 2100,
                                "accept": false
                                },
                                {
                                "id": 2,
                                "typeOfWorks": "Podłogi",
                                "costOfMaterials": 2650,
                                "costOfWorks": 1800,
                                "accept": true
                                },
                                {
                                "id": 3,
                                "typeOfWorks": "Okna",
                                "costOfMaterials": 1200,
                                "costOfWorks": 450,
                                "accept": true
                                },
                                {
                                "id": 4,
                                "typeOfWorks": "Drzwi",
                                "costOfMaterials": 850,
                                "costOfWorks": 250,
                                "accept": true
                                }

                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "roomId": 3,
                        "roomName": "Pokój",
                        "roomRows": [
                            {   
                                "id": 1,
                                "typeOfWorks": "Malowanie ścian",
                                "costOfMaterials": 1500,
                                "costOfWorks": 2100,
                                "accept": false
                                },
                                {
                                "id": 2,
                                "typeOfWorks": "Podłogi",
                                "costOfMaterials": 2650,
                                "costOfWorks": 1800,
                                "accept": true
                                },
                                {
                                "id": 3,
                                "typeOfWorks": "test Okna",
                                "costOfMaterials": 1200,
                                "costOfWorks": 450,
                                "accept": true
                                },
                                {
                                "id": 4,
                                "typeOfWorks": "Drzwi",
                                "costOfMaterials": 850,
                                "costOfWorks": 250,
                                "accept": true
                                }
                        ]
                    },
                        {
                        "roomId": 4,
                        "roomName": "Balkon",
                        "roomRows": [
                            {   
                                "id": 1,
                                "typeOfWorks": "Malowanie ścian",
                                "costOfMaterials": 1500,
                                "costOfWorks": 2100,
                                "accept": false
                                },
                                {
                                "id": 2,
                                "typeOfWorks": "Podłogi",
                                "costOfMaterials": 35555650,
                                "costOfWorks": 1800,
                                "accept": true
                                },
                                {
                                "id": 3,
                                "typeOfWorks": "Okna",
                                "costOfMaterials": 1200,
                                "costOfWorks": 450,
                                "accept": true
                                },
                                {
                                "id": 4,
                                "typeOfWorks": "Drzwi",
                                "costOfMaterials": 850,
                                "costOfWorks": 250,
                                "accept": true
                                }
                        ]
                    },
                ]

            },


        ];
        return {renovations};
    }

}
```

That's all works fine but look ugly. Can I write that code with ngFor? I try many times but I do something wrong. Maybe I have error in data.json? 
thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following code :

```html
<ng-container *ngFor="let room of renovations[0].rooms ">
    <h3>{{room.roomName }} hhhh {{room.roomId }}</h3>
    
     <table class="table" border="1">
                            <thead>
                            <!-- SORTOWANIE -->
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Lp</th>
                                    <th>Rodzaj robót</th>
                                    <th>Koszt materialów</th>
                                    <th>Koszt robocizny</th>
                                    <th>Akceptacja</th> 
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr *ngFor="let roomRow of room.roomRows">
                                    <td>{{roomRow.id}}</td>
                                    <td>{{roomRow.typeOfWorks}}</td>
                                    <td>{{roomRow.costOfMaterials}}</td>
                                    <td>{{roomRow.costOfWorks}}</td>
                                    <td>{{roomRow.accept}}</td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
    
       </table>
</ng-container>
```

explanation of code: so the first **ngFor** iterate the **rooms** of  the first renovation, after this we have a room contain a list of **romRow** so the second **ngFor** iterate the **romRows** of one **room**.

Comment: Would you mind explaining the code and changes in it to make it useful to future readers in an [edit]?